# Windows socket accepting and receiving at random

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I just finished my cross platform socket wrapper. It work well on Linux but on Window I get a very strange behavior.

When I launch my server (on loopback port 4242), the program start accepting connections from random sources and receiving from those connection.

Example of what is logged in my terminal (this happened at a very hight pace continously):

```
New client connected : 0.0.0.0:58030
Forwarding connection to worker in threadpool...
Waiting for client request...
New client connected : 0.0.0.0:58031
Received 4294967295 bytes from client ''
Forwarding connection to worker in threadpool...
Waiting for client request...
New client connected : Waiting for client request...
Received 4294967295 bytes from client ''0.0.0.0:Received 4294967295 bytes from client ''

58032
Waiting for client request...
Waiting for client request...
Received 4294967295 bytes from client ''
Received 4294967295 bytes from client ''Forwarding connection to worker in threadpool...
```

Here we can see 3 connections are accepted form `0.0.0.0:58030`, `0.0.0.0:58031` and `0.0.0.0:58032`. For each connection `Recv` return a huge number of byte read but the actual buffer is empty.

Any idea of what can cause this sort of behavior to orient my research ?

Comment: 2^32 equals 4294967296, 4294967295 is therefore likely a result of negative overflow. You use `unsigned` integer and subtract below 0. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=4294967295+, there are over 3k questions with 4294967295 on StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 3):

4294967295 is -1 cast to unsigned.  So you are getting -1 probably to indicate some socket error, and treating it as an unsigned number of bytes.

Comment: Functions like `recv()` and `send()` return signed `int` values. They return -1 on error, 0 on disconnect (`recv` only), and > 0 on bytes read/written.